# Избавиться от отступов между колонками (Bootstrap)

Tags: css, вёрстка, bootstrap

При использовании бутстраповской сетки, если располагать блоки в ряд, получаются большие отступы. Как можно исправить эту проблему, то есть вообще убрать этот отступ без изменения верстки?

https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FQOW6X8K0GBU[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: только если задать фиксированную высоту. Колонки оборачиваются в _div.row_ и соответственно высота по максимальной высоте колонки в строке.

Comment: пересобрать bootstrap под свои нужды. В переменных это задаётся.

Answer (score 0):

Такое получается при отличии колонок по высоте. В качестве фикса применяете для row следующие стили: "display: flex; flex-flow: row wrap;"